# What is the most efficient way to append a small amount of data to a large XML file?

Tags: java, apache-commons, stax

Every day my program runs once and collects about 300kB which are results from an HTPP GET request. It saves this data into a new XML file (`daily.xml`) and posts it to a database.

I also  a large 6GB+ XML file (`archive.xml`) that I want to incrementally add `daily.xml` to. To give a full picture, my XML Schema looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><add>
    <doc>...</doc>
    <doc>...</doc>
    <doc>...</doc></add>
```

Note I have separated `<doc>` elements on a new line, but the real file has everything on one line (important for option 2 below):

I know that StAX cannot 'modify' XML files. So it seems that the following options are available:

**1. Continue to use StAX, and use a temp "combine" file**

I could write all 6GB + 300 kB to a temp file and rename. That is, to maintain XML integrity, I could use StAX to read and combine `archive.xml` and `daily.xml` and write to `archive.temp.xml`, then rename to archive.xml to overwriting the older file.

Instinctively it feels inefficient to copy a large file for the sake of adding a ~300kB. Not to mention it is quite expensive on disk space, e.g. requiring ~2x6GB space for a short time.

**2. Ignore StAX implementation and revert to string manipulation of file**

This involves a few steps that I see as follows:

- Find the root element
- Use a string tool to go through the file and remove the tail root element. It wouldn't be as simple as removing the last line becuase the file is only one line.
- Open the file in APPEND mode using a BufferedWriter, or nio2 equivalent e.g. FileChannel and add `daily.xml`
- Write the tail root element `</add>` and close the file

  The second bullet, to open the file and find/remove the tail root element doesnt seem efficient.

**3. Use string manipulation and RandomAccessFile**

Java has a [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class that would allow me to modify `archive.xml` by placing the cursor. Similar steps to above would be needed, e.g. I would need to find the trailing root element and insert daily text.

It's a native class so I can't tell how efficient it is without building tests, but search results make it seem like a fairly inefficient means of manipulating large files (i.e. it's slow).

Is there a common practice for doing this? How would a text editor do the same thing?

Comment: How about not using an XML file for your archive, but rather, a text file where each new line is a single `<doc>`? It's easy enough to read such a file and reconstruct the data from it, and you can append to it without the problems you mention.

Comment: Indeed, I would store the data in a more efficient format, only creating the XML when needed. Not a good choice to manipulate an XML file.

Comment: One single 6GB+ File is not a good idea regardless a format, IMHO. Why not split the archive in reasonably big chunks? (And maybe zip older ones?)

Comment: I am thinking of splitting the file into years e.g. 2015.xml, 2014.xml etc.. which would reduce the size to a few hundred meg each, but the same issue applies. I need to append the most recent data to the file and they're still too big to be DOM manipulated. Reverting to non XML e.g. separate lines for `<doc>` and reconstructing might be the way to go.

Comment: The real problem here is using XML as a storage format.

Comment: XML is necessary as the storage format becuase ultimately the data is POSTed to a search engine db (requiring XML format) in 1 meg chunks. The purpose of having archive.xml is to maintain a backup incase it needs to be reconstructed.